# Verificar si un fichero existe en c++

Tags: c++

¿Como funciona esto?

la función stat devuelve una structura stat si no hay problema al verificar el estado de un fichero, si no hay problema lo guarda en buffer y retorna 0, de lo contrario retorna -1?
?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/stat.h>
int main(){
    struct stat buffer;
    if (stat("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Carpeta",&buffer)){
        mkdir("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Carpeta");    
    }
    else{
    std::cout<<"Fichero ya existente.";
    }
    
        
    return 0;
}
```

¿Hay alguna forma mas facil de hacerlo en C++11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Hay alguna forma mas facil de hacerlo en C++11?

No

Aun así, queda más usable si lo encapsulas en una función:

```
bool fileExists( std::string const& name )
{
  struct stat buffer;   
  return (stat(name.c_str(), &buffer) == 0); 
}
```

Aunque si no te gusta este modelo, que por cierto es uno de los más óptimos, puedes optar por usar `ifstream`:

```
bool fileExists( std::string const& name )
{
    ifstream f(name.c_str());
    return f.good();
}
```

Comment: El funcionamiento que explique es el correcto o funciona de otra manera?

Comment: @Franco es correcto aunque mejorable. Te aprovechas de una característica del lenguaje que dice que en la conversión de `int` a `bool`, todo es `true` salvo el 0. En tu caso parecería que `stat` devuelve un booleano cuando no es así